# How can I configure Module::Build to NOT install files as read-only?

Tags: windows, perl, module-build

I've encountered a scenario where I'm building a Perl module as part of another Build system on a Windows machine.  I use the `--install_base` option of Module::Build to specify a temporary directory to put module files until the overall build system can use them.  Unfortunately, that other Build system has a problem if any of its files that it depends on are read only - it tries to delete any generated files before rebuilding them, and it can't clean any read-only files (it tries to delete it, and it's read only, which gives an error.)  By default, [`Module::Build`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Module%3a%3aBuild) installs its libraries with the read-only bit enabled.

One option would be to make a new step in the build process that removes the read-only bit from the installed files, but due to the nature of the build tool that will require a second temporary directory...ugh.

Is it possible to configure a `Module::Build` based installer to NOT enable that read-only bit when the files are installed to the --install_base directory?  If so, how?

Comment: I've had severe issues with this too, and I'd have to dig back to see what we did about it. If you want to talk about it in private, since I can't disclose all of the details publicly, let me know.

Comment: @brian: Thanks for the offer; I won't take you up on it now (found a work-around: I force the tool to NOT delete them on a clean) but maybe some time else if this work-around fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it's not a configurable option.  It's done in the `copy_if_modified` method in `Module::Build::Base`:

```
# mode is read-only + (executable if source is executable)
my $mode = oct(444) | ( $self->is_executable($file) ? oct(111) : 0 );
chmod( $mode, $to_path );
```

If you controlled the Build.PL, you could subclass `Module::Build` and override `copy_if_modified` to call the base class and then `chmod` the file writable.  But I get the impression you're just trying to install someone else's module.

Probably the easiest thing to do would be to install a copy of `Module::Build` in a private directory, then edit it to use `oct(666)` (or whatever mode you want).  Then invoke `perl -I /path/to/customized/Module/Build Build.PL`.  Or, (as you said) just use the standard `Module::Build` and add a separate step to mark everything writable afterwards.

**Update:** ysth is right; it's [ExtUtils::Install](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?ExtUtils%3a%3aInstall) that actually does the final copy.  `copy_if_modified` is for populating `blib`.  But ExtUtils::Install also hardcodes the mode to read-only.  You could use a customized version of ExtUtils::Install, but it's probably easier to just have a separate step.

Comment: are you sure copy_if_modified isn't just used to copy into blib/?  I think the actual installation is done with ExtUtils::Install (which hardcodes 0444 (+0111 if any execute bit is set on the source)), but I gave up looking at the code before determining for certain.

Comment: This is exactly where my investigation led, thanks for the confirmation!